# Is MODOK planned to appear in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers

If so, is there any previously-shown character who's set to become him? (I didn't notice anybody named George Tarleton at any time.) Any rumors?

In my opinion, a live-action version of the already-creepy MODOK ‐ *especially* if you can recognize the distorted face as that of the actor ‐ would be absurdly, gloriously, epically disturbing.

Make him as evil as he's shown in *Marvel 1985* and he could become the greatest villain in the MCU, even while being far from the most powerful.

Comment: He could also become the second-greatest. Maybe even the third. Possibly the fourth.

Comment: See also: [Is this a M.O.D.O.K. reference?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/159225/13024)

Answer (score 4):

M.O.D.O.K. appeared as a boss in [*Iron Man 3: The Official Game*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_3:_The_Official_Game), a mobile game tie-in to (you guessed it) *Iron Man 3*:

[image: Killian as M.O.D.O.K.]

In the game, he's an enhanced version of [Aldrich Killian](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Aldrich_Killian), the main antagonist from *Iron Man 3* and founder and CEO of Advanced Idea Mechanics (A.I.M.).

Obviously the canonicity of video game tie-ins is questionable.

Christopher Markus, writer of the *Captain America* franchise, has expressed interest in bringing M.O.D.O.K. into *Civil War*, as he said in [an interview with SFX](http://www.gamesradar.com/exclusive-marvel-screenwriters-talk-winter-soldier-and-captain-america-3/), but finds it unlikely that it'd be approved:

> **SFX:** You managed to get Batroc and Sharon Carter into *The Winter Soldier*. Were there other Cap characters you were keen to bring to the screen but couldn’t quite fit into the second film?
>
> **CM:**  I don’t know if there’s anybody that we had in the wings that we couldn’t pull off. There are people that I’m always wanting to bring in. I want to put Modok into something, but you can’t just drop a giant floating head in! It’s not like “Oh, we have to go talk to this guy – there’s something I should tell you about him first…” [laughs]. Suddenly the whole movie needs to take on that structure in order to accommodate him. I never win that fight!

If there are any more substantial plans, I can't find any comment from Marvel.

Comment: He has also appeared in a Marvel LEGO set, which is an odd choice considering he's not a very well-known character outside comicdom.

Comment: @CreationEdge He's appeared in some of the cartoons; I guess they figured that was good enough?