# Is this a M.O.D.O.K. reference?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

On *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, the Superior, having been placed in a robot body, says that said body is (word-for-word) "designed only for killing."  Seeing as he is now a "mechanical organism," this might render him "a [mechanized organism designed only for killing."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MODOK)

Is there any confirmation that this is an intentional reference, be it interviews or other similarities of this version of the Superior to Modok?

Comment: I'd love to see how they would handle MODOK in a live action movie or show. The way he looks and the fact he levitates would mean a ton of CGI every time he was on screen, so would require massive budget. They might just stick him in a suped up wheelchair... but then he wouldn't really be MODOK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TL;DR: Officially, he is not MODOK, and they can't say if he's based on him or not.

Unofficially?

[image: wink wink]

---

There are definitely a few similarities which can't be totally ignored.

**First, at this point, they're really just disembodied heads with robot bodies.**

[image: MODOK Superior]
*MODOK Superior*

[image: sorry, I lost my head]
*Anton Ivanov*

While Ivanov does not have a creepy spider-like body like his possible namesake, he does utilize robot bodies.

**Next is their names.**

[Antony Ivanov](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Superior) is also known as *The Superior*, a likely reference to one of the versions of MODOK known as [MODOK Superior](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/M.O.D.O.K._Superior_(Earth-616)).

**Last is the almost direct shoutout.**

Ivanov mentions in [*The Return* (S04E21)](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d&episode=s04e21)

> Destroy this body, sure. It was **designed only for killing.** My head, which you severed, is controlling many of these machines now.

While the letters behind the acronym "MODOK" change from time to time, one of the versions is **M**echanized **O**rganism **D**esigned **O**nly For **K**illing.

---

That said, Entertaiment Weekly [specifically asked the producers/writers about this](http://ew.com/tv/2017/02/21/agents-shield-hydra-ward-return/).

> *Anton’s head is in a glass case. Has Anton become MODOK?*
>
> WHEDON: Well, no, we can’t really say what he is. He’s definitely his own creature, but we can’t comment really as to if he’s based on a Marvel character or not.
>
> *If I were to ask if his head goes in a particular part of his new synthetic body, what would you guys say?*
>
> WHEDON: We would say no. He’s remote controlling the body with a head because Aida wants to make sure that his humanness remains intact.

Comment: Can't comment if he is based on a Marvel character?  Sounds like not giving away spoilers to an extent, though I can't see them altering a character's back story that drastically.
MODOK isn't on the restricted list AFAIK.

Comment: In tonight's episode he referred to himself (droid body) " Designed Only for Killing"

Comment: @Naib There was no new episode "tonight' or "yesterday", and I already mentioned the "designed only for killing quote".

Comment: There was in the UK :) prob the same episode for the "Designed Only for Killing"